# How to call a function instead of implementing closure

Tags: ios, swift

I have this function

```
func performNetworkRequest(timeout: Int, completion: (Result<Response, Error>) -> Void) {
    // ....
}
```

I want to be able to call `performNetworkRequest` without writing the closure, but to pass an function to do the logic's over there.

something like :

```
func onNetwotkResponse(result: (Result<Response, Error>) -> Void) {
    
}

performNetworkRequest(timeout: 60, completion: onNetwotkResponse)
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of closure is:

```
(Result<Response, Error>) -> Void
```

which means

> A function that accepts a `Result<Response, Error>` and returns `Void`.

This means that your `onNetwotkResponse` function should accept `Result<Response, Error>`, rather than `(Result<Response, Error>) -> Void`:

```
func onNetwotkResponse(result: Result<Response, Error>) {
    
}
```